# Вывести из БД уникальный номер очереди

Tags: php, mysql

```
Существует таблица с заявлениями пользователей. Эти заявления поданы в разные детские сады. И что-то не пойму как правильно сформировать номер очереди.

Место в очереди:
- Дет. сад - Возраст - Категория
И в ней относительно времени подачи заявления, кто первее подал тот и выше место в очереди.
Например:
Иванов А.И. подал заявление 01.09.13
В дет. сад №1, в 3-летнюю группу, очередник
У него 1 место.
Петров А.И. подал заявление 02.09.13
В дет. сад №1, в 3-летнюю группу, очередник
У него 2 место.
Сидоров А.И. подал заявление 03.09.13
В дет. сад №2, в 3-летнюю группу, очередник
У него 1 место.

$req = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `statement_doy` WHERE `id_user`=".$user['id']." ORDER BY `id` ASC");                  
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($req))
    {
    $nomer++;
    echo '<tr>
    <td style="text-align: center">'.$row['f_baby'].' '.$row['i_baby'].' '.$row['o_baby'].'</td>
    <td style="text-align: center">'.$row['data_r'].'</td>
    <td style="text-align: center">'.$row['z_f'].' '.$row['z_i'].' '.$row['z_o'].'</td>';
    echo '<td style="text-align: center">'.$nomer.'</td>';
    if($row['moderation']==1)echo '<td style="text-align: center"><font color="green">допущено</font></td>';
    if($row['moderation']==2)echo '<td style="text-align: center"><font color="red">на проверке</font></td>';
    if($row['moderation']==3)echo '<td style="text-align: center"><font color="blue">отклонена</font></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `statement_doy` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
`moderation` int(1) NOT NULL default '2',
`status` int(11) NOT NULL default '2',
`nomer` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
`f_baby` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`i_baby` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`o_baby` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`data_r` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`vozrast_groups_doy` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`cat_baby` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`pol` int(1) NOT NULL,
`document_tip` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`serial_doc` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`nomer_doc` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`data_out_doc` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`ulica` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`dom` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`kvartira` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`data_post` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`lgoty` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
`potrebnost_zd` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`spec_potrebnost` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`predstavitelstvo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`z_f` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`z_i` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`z_o` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`z_email` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`z_telefond` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
`z_telefonm` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`z_telefonr` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`doy` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`prim` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
`time` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT
CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Сортировка сначала по Саду, потом по Дате (обратная). 

Как только изменился сад, обнуляете Счетчик очереди.

И все.

Comment: @vitagame, оформите свой вопрос по-человечески. Уберите лишнее, оставьте самое главное. Нафига здесь, к примеру, style?

Answer (score 1):

Разведите данные по таблицам. В таблице заявлений должны быть как минимум три поля:

```
id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
id_user int NOT NULL,
actual bool DEFAULT true
```

Сюда можно добавить ссылки на садики и группы - это на ваше усмотрение.

Поле id будет использоваться для сортировки. По умолчанию новая запись в очереди - актуальна. Когда заявка обработана, значение меняется на false.

Чтобы получить номер в очереди, находим id записи об очереди для конкретного пользователя (вложенный запрос), потом считаем те записи, которые меньше этого id и прибавляем к результату единицу (COUNT(*)+1):

```
   SELECT COUNT(*)+1 AS turn
     FROM turn
    WHERE actual = true
      AND id < (SELECT id 
                  FROM turn 
                 WHERE id_user = 987 /* id пользователя */ );
```

Если вы хотите получить очередь в конкретный садик (в таблице есть поле id_org) корректируем запрос так:

```
   SELECT count(*)+1 AS turn
     FROM turn
    WHERE actual = true
      AND id < (SELECT id 
                  FROM turn 
                 WHERE id_user = 987 /* id пользователя */ )
      AND id_org = 123; /* id садика */
```

Аналогично решаетеся вопрос с группой.

Comment: Забыли учесть, что для каждого садика - очередь отдельная.

Comment: @SilverIce, не забыл. Второй запрос выводит очередь по садику (обратите внимание на AND id_org...)

Comment: Ну в общем да наверно. Сорри.

Глянул только на описание таблицы в самом начале.

Comment: Добавил структуру таблицы в первый пост.

Comment: @vitagame, обратите внимание на первый абзац моего ответа. У меня такое чувство, что у вас всего одна таблица в БД. И это, мягко скажем, решение не очень хорошее.

Comment: А зачем здесь несколько таблиц? Все заявления хранятся в одной табличке.

Comment: Смысл базы данных в оптимальном хранении данных, а у вас - всё в кучу. Как минимум - потенциальная опасность повторения введенных данных, данные неунифицированные, сложность поиска по текстовым полям... Оно у вас, конечно заработает, но в общем - очень некрасивое решение. Почитайте про нормализацию баз данных.

Comment: Все данные, относящиеся к заявлению, в одной табличке. Разве неудобно?
Нужно реализовать как есть, с одной таблицей.


<pre><code>$nomer = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT count(*)+1 AS statement_doy
     FROM statement_doy
    WHERE moderation = 1
      AND id < (SELECT id 
                  FROM statement_doy 
                 WHERE id_user = ".$user['id'].")
      AND doy = ".$row['doy'].""));</code></pre>


В чем ошибка?

Comment: Смысл базы данных в оптимальном хранении данных... Ну или возьмите MS Excel и сделайте в нем. И проще, и быстрее.

Comment: Посмотрите запрос, который выше написал.